# how do i find the values of A,B and C in java

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, numbers

given the following values X,Y,Z, such as  (0≤X,Y,Z≤10000) with considering the following three equations :

1. a+b+c = X
2. abc = Y
3. a^2 + b^2+ c^2 = Z

i need to find values of a, b and c, I wrote something like this in java:

```
    for (int a = 0 ; x<= num; x++){
        for(int b =0 ; y<=num; y++){
            for(int c=0 ; z<=num; z++){
                int power = (int) Math.pow(a,2) + (int) Math.pow(b,2)+ (int) Math.pow(c,2); 
                if((x+y+z == X) && (x*y*z==Y) && (power==Z)){
                    System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("no values found");
```

but its a naïve solution because the values of  a,b and c can be zero, positive or negative numbers and must be distinct (a≠b≠c).

**for example:**

- input: 6 6 14 - output: 1 2 3
- input: 1 2 3 - output : no values found

input represent x,y,z and output represent a,b,c. can someone please put me on the right path and help me.

Comment: Have you considered rearranging the equations to a form of `f(b,c,X,Y,Z)` and solve for `a`.  Then you would only need two loops.  Further reductions may also be possible.

Comment: yes i have used 2 loops for b and c and solve for a 
like this a= X- (b+c)  but still got wrong answers. @WJS

Comment: `a,b,c` are the zeroes of the polynomial `t^3 - X*t^2 + (X^2-Z)/2*t - Y`

Comment: For the 3rd example, doesn't `-4^2 + -6^2 + 10^2 = 152` and not `48`?

Comment: @coproc, I'm sorry I'm not an expert programmer, how do i implement that

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, both symbolab.com and google calculator answers are 48

Comment: @NadaAlbargawi Then you must have miskeyed the entry, because the correct answer is 152.  Squaring negative numbers yields a positive result, so it's 16 + 36 + 100, which is 152.

Comment: Given the equations in the question, `-4^2` is assumed to be `(-4)^2`, not `-(4^2)`; so, it evaluates to `16`, not `-16`.

Comment: thanks guys you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want (or can) solve it analitically and the solutions are guaranteed to be integers (or you're only looking for integer solutions) then this code will work and also handle negative numbers:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestIntEquation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        long X=in.nextLong();
        long Y=in.nextLong();
        long Z=in.nextLong();

        int[] sign= {1,-1};
        
        for (long a=0;a*a<=Z;a++) {
            for (long b=0;a*a+b*b<=Z;b++) {
                long c=(long) Math.sqrt(Z-a*a-b*b);
                if (a*a+b*b+c*c!=Z) continue;
                long mul=a*b*c;
                if (mul!=Math.abs(Y)) continue;
                for (int signA: sign) {
                    for (int signB: sign) {
                        for (int signC: sign) {
                            if (signA*a==signB*b||signA*a==signC*c||signB*b==signC*c) continue;
                            long sum=signA*a+signB*b+signC*c;
                            mul=signA*a*signB*b*signC*c;
                            if (sum==X&&mul==Y) {
                                System.out.println(a*signA+" "+b*signB+" "+c*signC);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("no values found");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, really appreciated. wish you a wonderful day for helping